# I want to show some custom things on wordpress site and when user click on that he should get to other page where more info of that thing is there

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress Some one please guide me in this.
I want to make a section in my site where i should show some tools eg. zoom, teams, meet etc. that tools have to be dynamic and only the recent one will be shown. when user clicks on the tool he should be moved to other page where more info about that project is shown. What will be best way to this please guide me.
I had thought of some solution

1. Create pages of every tool.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to mean that you have a custom (self programmed) theme?

Where for example three items are shown and that when you click on that item, a new page opens with the content attached to that item?

Does that item come from the Wordpress/post or do you create it manually?
[image]

Please, next time, [show the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that you have already used.

Comment: For your information, I was not the one that downvoted your post.